# Power View to OLAP in Sharepoint - how do I add custom MDX

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powerview, olap

We have just enabled Power View in Sharepoint.

We do not have any tabular models set up but we have lots of OLAP cubes.

I am able to create the correct connection to one of our cubes and then create a Power View report that consumes that connection.

Is it possible to edit the `MDX` used by this report? If so how?

Comment: Editing the MDX is matter of Excel, not SharePoint. Even if you will not have full access to MDX syntax you can still work with sets and measures from Excel.

Comment: @EmilianoPoggi so save the power view report file in sharepoint but then open the file from excel and I will be able to edit the mdx? (please note: I am not using power pivot at all in the above scenario)